# C++ find word in string multiple times

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I'm currently trying to find a word inside a string. I'm using `string::find()`. However this only finds the word in the string for one time.

```
string a = "Dog";
string b = "I have a dog, his name is dog";

if (b.find(a) != string::npos)
{
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to scan string `b` to see how many times the word "dog" appears?

Comment: Use a loop until you can't find anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The most elegant way to iterate the words of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/the-most-elegant-way-to-iterate-the-words-of-a-string)

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst No, that's very different. We don't want every word here. Just where the one word can be located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop until you can't find anymore.

```
std::size_t count = 0, pos = 0;
while ((pos = b.find(a, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
    pos += a.size(); // Make sure the current one is skipped
    count++;
}
// Now you have count
```

Comment: @Galik Makes sense. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Setting pos += a.size() still causes an infinite loop. The while sets pos = 1 when found, and then it will hit pos += a.size(), which sets pos = 4, which doesn't get me anywhere!

Comment: @TysonB. I'm not sure how you got to this point, but according to [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), it should end reliably.

Comment: @TysonB. Whatever you think. I didn't meant to be aggressive. But next time please copy and paste from answers before reporting errors.

Comment: @TysonB. The while sets `pos` to the position of the search word if found. So you can guarantee to be able to add the length of the search word to `pos` because otherwise it would never have been found and the code to increment it would never have been called.